# Vector space on finite commutative set with $q$ elements

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $K$ be a finite field with $q$ elements and $V$ a $k$-vector space of dimension n. Then:
>
> (a) V is a finite set with $q^n$ elements.
>
> (b) Number of bases $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ in $V$ is:
>
> $$(q^n-1)(q^n-q)...(q^n-q^{n-1})$$
>
> (c) Number of sets of vectors $\{v_1,...,v_m\}$ in $V$ liniar independent is:
>
> $$N(n,m) = (q^n-1)(q^n-q)...(q^n-q^{m - 1})$$
>
> (d) Number of subspace in $V$ of dimension $\leq n$ is:
>
> $$S(n,m)=\frac {(q^n-1)(q^n-q)...(q^n-q^{m - 1})}{(q^m - 1)(q^m-q)...(q^m-q^{m-1})}$$

I have no idea how to start proving or disproving any of these statements since in class we worked only with infinite fields and we have no theory for these kind of problems with finite field... I know you will dislike my question but please.. give me some hints or a place to start..

Comment: Please have a look at Chapter 11(Vector Spaces), Section 11.1, Examples section just after Theorem 6( Page: 412) Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote